JQuery javascript search filter not updating clearing value
I have the following javscript code which filters a table based on search criteria in the SearchInput field. I then added a clear button called clearSearch which is designed to empty the search field. It works to a certain extent until I clear what I type in the search which sets value of the search field as blank but at this point the search doesn't update.
Any ideas how I can make the search reflect the clearing function?
Thanks
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#SearchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#Data tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

  $("#clearSearch").click(function(){
  $("#SearchInput").val("");
  });

});


Setting the value to an empty string via script, will of course not fire the keyup handler. But you should be able to simply trigger the event, after emptying the value: $("#SearchInput").val("").trigger("keyup");

I'm not sure .filter() is the best approach here, you're not doing anything with the returned elements. If you just want to run .toggle() on each element, you should look at using .each()

After clearing the input field with $("#SearchInput").val("");, you call $("#SearchInput").trigger("keyup");
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#SearchInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#Data tr").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });

  $("#clearSearch").click(function(){
    $("#SearchInput").val(""); 
    $("#SearchInput").trigger("keyup"); 
  });

});


Even shorter: $("#SearchInput").val("").trigger("keyup");
